# Key up and key down enabled on ios UIKeyboard

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikeyboard

We're trying to create a uikeyboard that will collect users key up and key down on every char press. The regular UITextField events gives us only the pressed change and not both of the times.

I've thought about trying to place a tranparent view over the keyboard but couldn't get a reference to the keyboard view. Also thought about creating my own keyboard but couldn't find any open source or online examples.

The ultimate goal is to get 2 callbacks on every key on the keyboard being pressed and for each click create an event with 2 timestamps (one for up and one for down) and the character that was pressed.

**SOLVED:**
Solved using a custom UIView that implements touchesBegin, touchesMoved, touchesEnded methods and forward the touches using hiTest function back to the main UIWindow.

Uri.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same now. Did you find any better solution as iOS will not support keyUp and keyDown events on Keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put a transparent view over the whole window by adding the view to the window itself (after the keyboard has popped!). Record all touchdowns and touchups and forward them. When you get a delegate message that a key was pressed, then you want know the last touches pair.

Comment: It sounds like a good direction, that way I wont need to find the keyboard window/view in a hacky way. My only question is how do I "forward them" to the real keyboard?

Comment: See "Forwarding Touch Events" in Apple's Event Handling Guide. You may want to first figure out where the keyboard view is located - my guess is that its the top subview of the window, and so will be the subview under your transparent view. That guide also suggests subclassing UIWindow as a way to see events before they get sent.